# Datagrid CancelEdit doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My DataGrid is defined in XAML:

```
<datagrid:ThemedDataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.ItemCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                 SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectedItem="{Binding Model.DatagridSelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</datagrid:ThemedDataGrid>
```

I have an Event `RowEditEnding` where I check if in a column already exists a cell with the same value previously entered. If it exists, then I need to cancel edit. My `RowEditEnding` method is below:

```
int counter = 0;
Model.ItemCollection.ForEach(x =>
{
    //if column is not empty
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name))
    {
        if (x.Name== Model.DatagridSelectedItem.Name)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Doubled Name");
                e.Cancel = true;
                datagrid.CancelEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row);                                                            
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is this line:

> datagrid.CancelEdit()

that doesn't change cell value to the previous one, and I get infinite loop. How can I solve it?

Comment: How is your RowEditEnding method called? Can't see the definition in XAML...

Comment: @Jan <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
                    <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnDatagridRowEditEnding"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your collection bound to the `ItemsSource` property populated with custom objects? If so, I think your custom data class has to implement the [IEditableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) interface.
Indeed from the [DataGrid documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> To guarantee that edits can be committed and canceled correctly, the
>   objects in the DataGrid must implement the IEditableObject interface.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using EF database-first; Which means every time I make an update to the database schema, I have to re-implement all the interfaces for all the tables. Do you think there is a work-around solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to leave out this:

```
datagrid.CancelEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row);
```

To my eyes, e.Cancel=true should do the job.

Comment: it does not cancell changes

Answer (score 0):

Implement IEditableObject Interface for your class.Which is a ObservableCollection.(Diagnostics is a class and Name is the property)

```
   private Diagnostics backupCopy;
   private bool inEdit;

   public void BeginEdit()
   {
       if (inEdit) return;
       inEdit = true;
       backupCopy = this.MemberwiseClone() as Diagnostics;
   }

   public void CancelEdit()
   {
       if (!inEdit) return;
       inEdit = false;
       this.Name= backupCopy.Name;
   }

   public void EndEdit()
   {
       if (!inEdit) return;
       inEdit = false;
       backupCopy = null;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my personal experience, replacing `datagrid.CancelEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row);` with `datagrid.EndEdit();` did the trick.

**Usage Example:**

In the GIF below, I have applied the method `.EndEdit()` to the second column (nothing is applied to the first column). As you can see, the first column allows the cell to be edited (a typing cursor appears), while the second column does not.

[image: EndEdit() Method Preventing Cel]

Comment: Add some description.

Comment: @Billa, thanks for the feedback! I'd altered my answer to have a bit more meat to it.